# Como armazenar dados em uma lista tipada usando a classe Scanner do Java

Tags: java, lógica, arraylist, scanner

Como armazenar as novas entradas(Scanner) para uma `ArrayList` já existente de uma determinada classe(User)?
A ArrayList que eu criei tem dois itens para serem preenchidos: Nome e sexo.
Não estou conseguindo achar uma solução para fazer isso pelo Scanner.
A lista no código abaixo teve os dados inseridos manualmente, queria saber como fazer o mesmo com input.
Estou aprendendo java agora, então relevem a ignorância.
Obrigado

***Classe User:***

```
    public class User implements Comparable<User>{
    private String nomeCompleto;
    private String sexoUsuario;

    public User(String nomeCompleto, String sexoUsuario) {
        this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
        this.sexoUsuario = sexoUsuario;
    }


    public String getNomeCompleto() {
        return nomeCompleto;
    }

    public void setNomeCompleto(String nomeCompleto) {
        this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
    }

    public String getSexoUsuario() {
        return sexoUsuario;
    }

    public void setSexoUsuario(String sexoUsuario) {
        this.sexoUsuario = sexoUsuario;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  '\n'+"Nome:" + nomeCompleto + ','+
               " Sexo:" + sexoUsuario
                ;
    }
    //Implementação do Comparable.
    @Override
    //'User' é o nome da classe.
    public int compareTo(User sexo) {
        return this.sexoUsuario.compareTo(sexo.getSexoUsuario());
    }
}
```

***Classe App:***

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        registroNomes();
}

private static void registroNomes(){
    //Lista tipada como User. Encontrado na Classe User.
    List<User> usuarios = new ArrayList<User>();
    System.out.println("Vamos começar o seu cadastro.");
    System.out.println("Digite o seu nome completo: ");

    //Usuarios
    User a = new User("Arthur Sousa", "Masculino");
    User b = new User("Josiel Rocha", "Masculino");
    User c = new User("Julha Catarina", "Feminino");
    User d = new User("Dara Cristina", "Feminino");
    User e = new User("Amanda Caroline", "Feminino");
    User f = new User("Sebastião Humberto", "Masculino");

    usuarios.add(a);
    usuarios.add(b);
    usuarios.add(c);
    usuarios.add(d);
    usuarios.add(e);
    usuarios.add(f);


    Collections.sort(usuarios);
    System.out.println(usuarios);

    }
```

}

Comment: colocar a instância da sua classe `User` dentro de um `loop` e vai adiciona as informações obtidas do `scanner` no seu `modelo` e depois na sua lista.

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro, eu estava não tinha chegado nesse raciocínio. Muito obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Então se eu entendi bem você quer que seja adicionado o usuários na lista pela terminal de execução ( prompt/cmd ).

A 1° etapa para realizar essa tarefa irá ser usar a classe [`Scanner`](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-funciona-a-classe-scanner-do-java/28448) do java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  }  
}
```

Com ela instanciada você vai notar que agora conseguimos realizar a inserção de  algum **texto** e também conseguimos **ler** textos inseridos no *terminal*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite algum texto: ");
    String texto = scanner.nextLine(); // lendo o texto inserido no terminal
    
    System.println("Você digitou: " + texto);
  
  }  
}
```

A 2° etapa é efetuar a captura dessas informações e inseri-las na lista.
Para fazer isso vou vai precisar instanciar a sua classe `User` para e inserir o que foi capturado nela através do *construtor*. Com o seu objeto `usuarioNovo` *populado* com as informações inseridas pelo *terminal*, basta agora adiciona-los na sua lista ( `usuarios` ).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    // lista onde irá ser armazendo seus usuários
    ArrayList<User> usuarios = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Digite seu nome completo: ");
    String nomeCompleto = scanner.nextLine(); // lendo o nome inserido no terminal
    
    System.out.println("Digite seu sexo: ");
    String sexo = scanner.nextLine(); // lendo o sexo inserido no terminal
  
    // instancia do novo usuário que irá ser inserido na lista
    User novoUsuario = User(nomeCompleto, sexo);
    usuarios.add(novoUsuario);

    scanner.close(); // fechando o scanner

  }  
}
```

Agora vamos a 3º etapa, essa talvez a que você esteja realmente tentando fazer, ***inserir vários registros na lista***.

Primeiro temos que determinar uma variável para controlarmos as inserções e o nosso programa na ficar em um `loop` **infinito**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    // lista onde irá ser armazendo seus usuários
    ArrayList<User> usuarios = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean controleFluxo = true; // variável que ira controlar o nosso fluxo dentro do loop ( while )
    
    while(controleFluxo) {
    
        //...
    
    }
    

  }  
}
```

Depois basta adicionar o código anterior dentro do `loop`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    // lista onde irá ser armazendo seus usuários
    ArrayList<User> usuarios = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Digite seu nome completo: ");
    String nomeCompleto = scanner.nextLine(); // lendo o nome inserido no terminal
    
    System.out.println("Digite seu sexo: ");
    String sexo = scanner.nextLine(); // lendo o sexo inserido no terminal
  
    // instancia do novo usuário que irá ser inserido na lista
    User novoUsuario = User(nomeCompleto, sexo);
    usuarios.add(novoUsuario);
    

  }  
}
```

E para finalizar colocamos uma condição dentro de um `if` para parar o `loop` quando quisermos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    // lista onde irá ser armazendo seus usuários
    ArrayList<User> usuarios = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean controleFluxo = true; // variável que ira controlar o nosso fluxo dentro do loop ( while )
    
    while(controleFluxo){
    
      System.out.println("Digite seu nome completo:");
      String nome = scanner.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Digite seu sexo:");
      String sexo = scanner.nextLine();

      User usuario = new User(nome, sexo);
      usuarios.add(usuario);
      
      // para o loop caso o usuário digite "N"
      if(resposta.equals("N")){
        controleFluxo = false;
        break;
      }
  }  
  
  scanner.close();
  
}
```

[Link do protótipo utilizado para responde a questão](https://replit.com/@drkla/httpsptstackoverflowcomquestions574857armazenar-inpu?v=1)

Comment: Note que no último `if` vc usa `break`, que serve para interromper o loop. Sendo assim, a variável `controleFluxo` se torna desnecessária: poderia ser `while (true)` e no `if` ter só o `break`

Comment: @hkotsubo valeu, é verdade não há necessidade da variável `controleFluxo`. Bem observado.

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Tô pegando o jeito de me condicionar mais nessa estrutura de repetição. Valeu pessoal